# Adding attributes to hibernate mapping file

Tags: java, hibernate

If I decorate the hibernate mapping xml file with additional attributes of my own is there a way to access these via the hibernate meta-model or would I have to access the xml document directly?

for instance:

```
<class entity-name="..." ....>
    ...
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" myNamespace:customAttr="someVal" />
</class>
```

Is there a way to access the "customAttr" ?

Comment: yup, you weren't clear. What behavour do you expect from that customAttr? Does hibernate support it?

Comment: I am using the meta-model to extract information about my domain model (via "ClassMetadata"). I want to add custom information to the mapping so that in the process of examining the meta-model I can get this additional information (which is specific to my domain and hibernate does not support it).  Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might not be an option in your context, but I would recommend specifying the meta-model by annotating model classes with JavaEE `javax.persistence` annotations.

That way you can easily add your custom attributes as custom annotations.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think hibernate supports it. Why don't you define your own XML to put up your attributes to avoid any clashes and headaches you might face in the future? Besides, it is not a good approach either!!! And when the Hibernate API is validating the XML, it won't take that, so you'll end up having to define your own XML.